# mod_rewrite query string

Tags: string, mod-rewrite

I have a query string like

```
search.php?id=12&keyword=abc&api=gIUTG6898
```

And I want the URL to be like this:

```
search/?id=12&keyword=abc&api=gIUTG6898
```

Now I found a lot of solutions but they are limited to only one variable in the query string. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It's not that complicated, since you just want to 'transfer' the query string. You can ignore it in the RewriteRule.

```
RewriteRule ^search/?$ search.php [QSA]
```

This just rewrites 'search/' to 'search.php'.

Comment: Did you set `RewriteEnginge On`?

Comment: yes I am using may other rewriting rules and they are working fine

Answer (score 0):

Since you are wanting to remove the .php and replace it with a slash, you'd need to reverse Floern's RewriteRule somewhat:

```
RewriteRule ^/search.php$ /search/ [QSA,L]
```